# How to make dynamic url-pattern using Spring MVC @PathVariable?

Tags: spring, spring-form

I'm working that make search function.
I have a search form on jsp view.

```
<form action="<c:url value="/community/board/list/search" />">
    <p class="serch_Area">
        <select name="searchCategory">
            <option value="subject" selected="selected">subject</option>
            <option value="contents">contents</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="searchWord" class="inputCom" style="width:150px; height:17px;" value="" maxlength="15" />
        <input type="image" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/common/btn_search.gif" />" alt="search" />
    </p>
</form>
```

I want to make request url-pattern like "/community/board/list/search/subject/abc". But this form action url like "/community/board/list/search?subject=abc"
How can I make request url pattern like RESTful?

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/list/search/{searchCategory}/{searchWord}/{pageNum}")
public String getSearchList(@PathVariable(value = "searchCategory") String searchCategory,
                            @PathVariable(value = "searchWord") String searchWord,
                            @PathVariable(value = "pageNum") int pageNum, ModelMap model) {
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript. You should add an `onSubmit` listener on your form and change your form action within that method.